# How Entity Framework works

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a dispute with my colegue about how Entity Framework interacs with MS SQL SERVER.

We are arguing about if Entity Framework loads all the values from Db tables in Objects or not.

EDITED: when we select data using LINQ i my opinion LINQ query works with entity objects not direct with tables so the information in objects where previously obtained from the table.

Comment: What do you mean? If it does a `SELECT * FROM Table1` without a `WHERE` always?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
It’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So EF is an ORM, when you ask it to, it will load what you want into Objects, defined as POCO. Plain Old CLR Objects

Comment: Note that it's a good "sport" to always check with the SQL Profiler the queries generated by EF/NHibernate, because they can be full of surprises. This will even show you how they work.

Comment: @xanatos, definitely agree with that. In fact EF will wrap the query in a Stored Procedure and execute it against the database

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb419139

Comment: if when the code calls "using DbEntities" statement the objects are loaded with the values from the tables. something like a SELECT statement. because when we select data using LINQ i my opinion LINQ query works with entity objects not direct with tables so the information in objects where previously obtained from the table

Comment: Ah... Ok... `IQueryable` vs `IEnumerable` :-) No, you are wrong :-) Your linq queries are translated "on the fly" to equivalent sql queries

Comment: so when i query with LINQ in fact i make a query on the Database

Comment: Yes. Can I over simplify it? Linq -> QueryProvider translation (SQL/Oracle) -> DatabaseEngine Processing  -> ResultSet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole idea behind EF is to solve the impedance between relational an object oriented worlds, so, I don't see the point in your question..

Comment: Ok... English isn't my first language, but I do know the use of an ORM and how it works... But what do you mean with **impedance**?

Comment: My question is if when i make a query with LINQ if i interact directly with the database or with entity through its objects. And if the objects are previously loaded with information from Database

Comment: @Relix Think about it. If EF loaded all the resultset into objects and you had an example query to just select the first row in a table that'd be awfully slow. The query is done at the db.

Comment: I understand. Thank you all for answers